# Не отрабатывает page:update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Есть мой учебный проект на ruby. Делаю редактирование объектов с помощью JS. Сейчас работает так: Редактирую первый раз - всё нормально. Не обновляя страницу, жму редактировать и видно, что происходит перечитывание объекта, но форма для редактирования не появляется. Жму третий раз - всё нормально (Как первый раз).

Вот ссылка на мой js код - [мой репозиторий](https://github.com/hawk911/RoR_extended/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ready.js)
  Вот этот код.

```
$('.edit-answer-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).hide()
  answer_id = $(this).data('answerId')
  $('form#edit-answer-' + answer_id).show()
});
```

Внизу есть:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
$(document).on('page:update', ready);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click` биндит события только для элементов, удовлетворяющих селектору, которые в данный момент есть на странице.

Рискну предположить что проблема в том, что при сабмите формы происходит обновление HTML, что приводит к тому, что старые бинды уже не будут отрабатывать для обновлённых элементов. Т.е. отрабатывает дефолтное поведение, а это переход по ссылке. Переход по пустой ссылке означает обновление страницы. На обновлённой странице события опять будут забинжены до обновления HTML.

Чтобы события перехватывались и для новых элементов, нужно использовать `on`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit-answer-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).hide()
  answer_id = $(this).data('answerId')
  $('form#edit-answer-' + answer_id).show()
});
```

[Подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements).

Comment: Изменил на `on` - так же. Не понятно почему

Comment: Не понятно почему нормально отрабатывает

Comment: $('.select-best-answer').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var answerId = $(this).data('answerId');
      var answerSelector = 'div[data-answer-id=' + answerId + ']'
      $(answerSelector).replaceWith("<%= j render @answer %>");
    });
p.s. По привычки нажимаю Enter и комментарий закрывается. Извините.

Comment: @DenisBogatyrev, исправил пример

Comment: Сработало. Благодарю.